# Получить из массива два массива, один с датами другой другой с суммами

Tags: php, массивы

Вообщем что-то я затупляю, но не как не могу найти решение;
Есть динамический массив примерно такого вида:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 66
        [created_at] => 2018-05-04
        [summa] => 2400000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 131
        [created_at] => 2018-05-07
        [summa] => 200000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 139
        [created_at] => 2018-05-07
        [summa] => 100000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 146
        [created_at] => 2018-05-15
        [summa] => 600000
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 154
        [created_at] => 2018-05-22
    )
)
```

Ну вроде простой массив, надо получить из него два массива один с датами другой другой с суммами, при этом если дата одна и таже то сумма на данный день складываются, а также порядковые номера в массивах должны соответствовать друг другу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

дак и заведите промежуточный массив, где даты будут ключами. Если ключ уже есть, то приплюсовываете значения.

```
$data = [
    ['created' => 'a', 'sum' => 1],
    ['created' => 'a', 'sum' => 2],
    ['created' => 'a', 'sum' => 3],
    ['created' => 'b', 'sum' => 1],
    ['created' => 'c', 'sum' => 10],
    ['created' => 'c', 'sum' => 0],
];


$tmp = [];
foreach($data as $d){
    if(array_key_exists( $d['created'], $tmp)){
        $tmp[$d['created']] += $d['sum'];
    }
    else $tmp[$d['created']] = $d['sum'];
}

$created = array_keys($tmp);
$sum     = array_values($tmp);
```

либо, используя некоторые функции для работы с массивами, можно сразу создать массив где ключами будут уникальные даты, а значения равны 0. После чего просто просуммировать значения

```
$tmp = array_fill_keys(array_column($data, 'created'),0);
foreach($data as $d){
     $tmp[$d['created']] += $d['sum'];
}
```